# How to change transparency of objects not selected?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a patch three style game.  I want to change the transparency of all the nodes that don't match a selected color.  So imagine you select purple, everything not purple I want to dim.

```
protected void matchByLinkedList()
{
    List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();  //makes a new list of nodes when touched
    Debug.Log(List<Node>);
    LinkedListNode<Node> linkedListNode = linkedList.First; //creates a list of the selected nodes.
    int element = linkedListNode.Value.element;  //This gets the value of the selected Node's element

}
```

Above is what I am using to make the selections.  `element` is a field I have put on the prefab to identify the color.  Red = 1, Purple = 2 etc..

Do I need to do a `foreach` that doesn't equal element (1) edit transform?  I feel like I am missing some steps in between in my thought process.

I don't really understand how I am supple to make a list of all items that don't match and then set the transform on those.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, generally it's better to avoid loops as much as possible. you can achieve this by having a static `Node` field in your `Node` class and compare `InstanceId` of any node with it.

```
public class Node : MonoBehaviour{

internal static Node SelectedNode;

//call this somehow
public void OnSelect(){
  SelectedNode = this;
}

void Update(){
  if(this.GetInstanceID() == SelectedNode.GetInstanceID())
  {
    //dim this
  }
}
}
```

### edit

make sure you don't compare the InstanceId of a GameObject with InstanceId of a Component or so. both Objects must have the same type or otherwise it always returns false.

Comment: Thanks I will try this